# From an String Array of ids get all objects from DynamoDB SDK Java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

What I want to achieve is from an String array of ids, get all items with those ids from the DynamoDB.
I actually accomplished that in a very lazy way:

```
public Note findNote(final String noteID) {
        DynamoDbTable<Note> noteTable = getTable();
        Key key = Key.builder().partitionValue(noteID).build();

        Note result = noteTable.getItem(key);
        return result;
    }

public ArrayList<Note> findNotes(String[] notes){
        ArrayList<Note> notess= new ArrayList<Note>();
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
           notess.add(findNote(notes[i]));
        }
        return notess;
    }
```

But its pretty inefficient, does the work, but for big arrays I will have do as many queries as the array length.

Any way to do this more efficient or with a single query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You want `batchGetItem()` where you can retrieve up to 100 in one call. The RCU cost is the same but the latency will improved due to less network traffic. You can find an example in the very useful AWS Samples repo:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/java/WorkingWithItems/BatchGetItem.java

Comment: tried using the code you linked, but have a problem, how will I pass the keys to ```BatchGetItemEnchancedRequest.builder()``` ?
I need to use  ```.addGetItem(k->k.key(key1))```, but not sure how to pass that function according to the number of items in my array, any ideas?
Should I make a different question for this one?